# Odoo Studio Bug

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

So we created some new custom fields through Odoo Studio by just dragging them into the view. The problem now is that suddenly these fields became BASE Fields instead of custom fields. We were trying to delete them but Odoo didnt let us.

[image]

So what can we do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the fields and any relationships they have with other fields from the xml